# Google Maps LatLngbounds not working

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I am implemented Google map v2 api in my android application. Here, in one activity I successfully init google map object. I successfully added five marker into the map and also current location that is fine.

Now, I want to see all these markers into the current screen using LatLngBounds.

Code is given below.

```
LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
for(Marker m : markers) {
     builder.include(m.getPosition());
}
LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 50));
```

but when I implement this there is no effect into map.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this? I am having more or less the same issue.

Comment: Ya put this logic into one thared and it's working. wait i posting my answer.

Comment: okay, I will try that, but for me it works for coordinates and doesn't  work for others.

Comment: @ M D, what is your solution please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem with adding markers to the map before:

```
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 50));
```

I just added:

```
_map.addMarker(nearestMarker);

_map.addMarker(_myLocationMarker);
```

My code looks like this:

```
CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 100, 100, 5);
_map.addMarker(nearestMarker);
_map.addMarker(_myLocationMarker);
_map.animateCamera(cu);
```

Hope this will help you.